# Filter questions by tags using ONLY

Tags: support, tags

I found how to filter questions using

- [tag1] AND [tag2]: `[tag1] [tag2]`
- [tag1] OR [tag2]: `[tag1] or [tag2]`
- [tag1] ANDNOT [tag2]: `[tag1]-[tag2]`

But can you filter "ONLY [tag1]"? That would be equivalent to pseudocode `[tag1]-[^tag1]` meaning [tag1] ANDNOT "any tag which is not tag1".

Comment: What use would such a search be? There currently is no way to find posts that have **just** that tag. I see clear use for *at least this tag*, and *at least this tag OR that tag* and *at least this tag AND that tag* but I see no use case for *only this tag*.

Comment: But you can find use in finding posts that have **just** the X tags you specify. *only this tag AND that tag*.

Comment: No, I cannot. You can state that the post must have *at least this tag AND that tag*. If there is a 3rd tag on that post then that post is not excluded.

Comment: When looking for Flask + SQLAlchemy tags, I don't care that there are extra tags beyond those two.

Comment: Well if I search for [java] + [eclipse] I DO care if there is also [android].

Comment: It's easy enough to [filter out android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+eclipse+-android) in that case, isn't there?

Comment: If it's only andriod, but there are tons of other things I don't need to see.

Comment: That's what the ignored tags feature is for.

Comment: So I need to add ALL of the tags I don't want to see to the ignored tags? That is clearly not a good way to do it.

Comment: There is an ever expanding number of tags, do you *really* want to filter out the rest of the world? There are only a dozen or so results in the first 100 hits on `java eclipse -android` that use *only* 2 tags.

Comment: I want to create such a filter for my convenience.

Comment: That's not a usecase currently supported, because that's what the ignored tags were meant for.

Comment: Well then, you may post an answer that it's not possible to do what I asked for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do what you want; there is no functionality to limit search to posts containing **only** the searched-for tags.

Because there are always more tags that you didn't think of, you'd be missing out too many posts in any case. Why would a question with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)[eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse)[ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide) be less interesting than just [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)[eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse)?

Instead, you can always explicitly remove *specific* tags with the `-[tagname]` syntax, and / or add uninteresting tags to your ignored tags list.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* the answer you're looking for is to setup favorite tags in your profile - you can then click them on the right of the page to filter by just that tag.

Comment: Clicking on a tag under "Favorite Tags" is the same as clicking the tag anywhere else, or just searching for it in the search box. Did you test it?

Comment: Hm, I may have misunderstood your question.. I fear that most people do not resort to a single tag though. So your query is likely to turn up very limited results, if you do get it working.

Comment: But if you have "ONLY" then I can use it as in ONLY [1tag1] [tag2].