# RSS feed for only one particular tag

Tags: support

Is there any possibility to get the question feed on only one particular tag and excluding questions if it is having multiple tags

For Example, I want to know questions only about C#.  I want to exclude questions that have C# XML tag or C# Asp.Net etc. How can I do that ?

Comment: Would seem to be a duplicate of [Filter questions by tags using ONLY](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251856/filter-questions-by-tags-using-only?rq=1), because if one could do that there would be an RSS feed for it.

Answer (score 4):

You can't get a feed for questions with just one specific tag only, but you can use the RSS feed from a [search result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+-xml+-asp.net) to combine and exclude tags.

[Newest questions tagged C#, not XML, not ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=c%23%20-xml%20-asp.net&sort=newest).

After looking through those results, you'll probably want to filter out [asp.net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) also.

Comment: What about e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/valgrind ?

Comment: @yugr What about it?

Comment: Wouldn't that be a "feed for questions with just one specific tag only"?

Comment: @yugr No, the [first question in that feed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54056875) has the tags `c`, `memory-management`, and `valgrind`. It's the feed for all valgrind questions.

Comment: Right, got it...