# A feature to select more than one tag

Tags: support, feature-request, tags

I wonder if there's a feature to select more than one tag to see their list of questions.

For instance I wanna see the list of questions that have **either** tags of *jQuery, CSS or HTML*.

If there isn't such a feature, why not include it?

You can do something almost similar to what I mean by searching for `[jQuery] or [CSS] or [HTML] is:question` which is fine, but then the user will not be alerted of the newly asked questions and they have to refresh the page, each time they wanna see newer questions! (unlike when you select a tag to see its questions)

Comment: Do you mean search like this: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery+or+css+or+html? For that you have to enter `[jquery] or [css] or [html]` in the search box.

Comment: [Use a custom search like this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bjQuery%5d%20or%20%5bCSS%5d%20or%20%5bHTML%5d%20is%3aquestion)

Comment: very good, thank you @InfiniteRecursion

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion but here comes another problem, if we do that, the new questions alert will not pop whenever a new question is asked, you have to refresh the page over and over in order to see the new questions

Comment: For that [you need](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256111/2982225) to [subscribe to rss feed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262360/2982225) @AminJafari. Here is the feed for [jQuery, CSS or HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=jQuery%5d%20or%20%5bCSS%5d%20or%20%5bHTML&sort=newest)

Comment: Are you getting pop-ups for every new question? Which Browser are you using? I don't get any pop-ups on chrome.

Comment: @AminJafari you don't have to refresh, just wait a bit and you will see there are new questions that meet the criteria. I do this all the time with `.../c%23+excel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> feature to select more than one tag to see their list of questions?

Search for multiple tags and use **or** between two tags, like this:

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery+or+css+or+html
```

You'll see questions which are tagged under either of these tags. In addition to that you'll also receive notifications whenever a new question is posted in either of these tags (so no need to refresh the page manually).

Comment: This also works and is a bit shorter: `http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery+or+css+or+html`

Comment: @user000001 thanks for sharing. To save time, I used the search box which gave this longer URL. :)