# How to make tag filtering send email to a mailing list?

Tags: support, filtering

I'm associated with a project that has a project mailing list.  I'm investigating the practicality of having new postings with particular tags being emailed to the project mailing list instead of specific users.  I personally use the email filtering feature to be notified of new posts with tags I want to know about, but I'd like to see if a larger audience (the people on the mailing list), could be notified without having to have each one of them set their SO filtering preferences.

Comment: Maybe use an [rss-feed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262357/rss-feed-for-only-one-particular-tag) and have an feed-service email the results?

Comment: I can see it would be feasible to write a Java app that checks the feed on a frequency and emails the result to a destination.  Are there any options for this that don't require deploying an app to do this, like a free cloud service?

Comment: This are recommendations I found on [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113630/subscribe-to-a-particular-question-by-email-not-rss) but if you need more recent suggestions you might search on [SR.se](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways you could do such a thing by working with the RSS feed(s) for the particular tag(s) (examples: `http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=javascript&sort=newest`, `http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=c%23+-xml+-asp.net&sort=newest`).

I would use [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com) (If This Then That) with the [Feed channel](https://ifttt.com/feed) (using the "New Feed item" trigger) and the [Email channel](https://ifttt.com/email) (using the "Send me an email" action). You'll be able to set it to whatever email address you want, although I expect you'll need to confirm that it's yours.

(Here's an [IFTTT recipe that sends a daily digest from new questions in a particular tag](https://ifttt.com/recipes/430775-get-daily-digest-from-stack-overflow-tag))

Comment: I don't understand how I would configure the email channel to send to a different email address.

Comment: Hmmm...I guess you'd have to have an IFTTT account for the mailing list. I agree that may make this a less than ideal solution.